# Add a custom language which is not already available in magento

Tags: magento

I have a magento installation and i want to add urdu language in Magento. I searched everywhere but could now find how to add and map Magento_base\app\locale\ur_PK in locale. Please someone guide me which can be the necessary setting and parameters i need to set for this. I already know how to add store view for different languages in Magento.

Problem is that i dont see Urdu language in System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Locale . So i cant map \app\locale\ur_PK folder to language

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have language package?

Comment: Yes i can see other urdu laguage web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You will need messing on library of zend , of one researched how to do in zend.

Basically you will have to create two files in xml, **ur.xml** and **ur_PK.xml** in **lib/Zend/Locale/Date**

Comment: Problem is that i dont see Urdu language in System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Locale . So i cant map \app\locale\ur_PK folder to language

Comment: Unfortunately no, I never had to add a language, only checked the settings to help you, but you had already created the xmls.

Answer (score 0):

In the file
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale/Config.php
in the Array $_allowedLocales
where is no "ur_IN" nor "ur_PK".
For this you will not be able to select Urdu in Backend.

Only "gu_IN" and "hi_IN" are available.

As a hack you can add "ur_IN" or "ur_PK" to the array.

Comment: i will try this today